# Tkinter Python Question: How to create a function in this program to make the variable year_of_birth and year_present together (Age Calculator)plshelp

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator, subtraction

```
from tkinter import *
def age_calculator():
    window=Tk()
    window.title("Age Calculator")
    label_one=Label(window,text="Welcome to Age Calculator",fg="green")
    label_one.pack()
    year_of_birth=Entry(window,width=5,bd=4)
    year_of_birth.place(x=210,y=100)
    label_two=Label(window,text="Year of Birth",fg="purple")
    label_two.place(x=200,y=70) 
    year_present=Entry(window,width=5,bd=4)
    year_present.place(x=470,y=100)
    label_three=Label(window,text="Year in Present",fg="red")
    label_three.place(x=450,y=70)
    l4=Label(window,text="=")
    l4.place(x=670,y=100)
    button1=Button(window,text="Calculate",fg="red",bg="green",command=mainCalcu)
    button1.place(x=800,y=100)

    window.mainloop()
age_calculator()
```

So I tryed using many methods I need a def fucntion which can subtract the year_present by year_of_birth and the output should be shown.

Comment: *"So I tryed using many methods"* - What have you tried? What issue did you come across?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it. If you want to change the message, on the line just below the comment that says 'Change output below'. the output variable is the output (hence the name output)

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Age Calculator")
label_one = Label(window,text="Welcome to Age Calculator",fg="green")
label_one.pack()
year_of_birth = Entry(window,width=5,bd=4)
year_of_birth.place(x=210,y=100)
label_two = Label(window,text="Year of Birth",fg="purple")
label_two.place(x=200,y=70) 
year_present = Entry(window,width=5,bd=4)
year_present.place(x=470,y=100)
label_three = Label(window,text="Year in Present",fg="red")
label_three.place(x=450,y=70)
l4 = Label(window,text="=")
l4.place(x=670,y=100)


def mainCalcu(year_of_birth, year_present):
  string1 = year_of_birth.get()
  string2 = year_present.get()
  calcedVal = int(string2) - int(string1)
  # The variable 'calcedVal' is the variable you can use in your output
  # Change output below
  output = Label(window, text = "You are " + str(calcedVal) + " years old!").place(x=670,y=150)

button1 = Button(window,text="Calculate",fg="red",bg="green", command = lambda: mainCalcu(year_of_birth, year_present))
button1.place(x=800,y=100)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It says NameError: year_of_birth

Comment: I've actually find a solution that I pretty sure will work. I've updated the answer to show my new solution.